# TypeError during executemany() INSERT statement using a list of strings

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to just do a basic INSERT operation to a PostgreSQL database through Python via the Psycopg2 module.  I have read a great many of the questions already posted regarding this subject as well as the documentation but I seem to have done something uniquely wrong and none of the fixes seem to work for my code.

```
#API CALL + JSON decoding here
x = 0
for item in ulist:
    idValue = list['members'][x]['name']
    activeUsers.append(str(idValue))
    x += 1

dbShell.executemany("""INSERT INTO slickusers (username) VALUES (%s)""", activeUsers
)
```

The loop creates a list of strings that looks like this when printed:

```
['b2ong', 'dune', 'drble', 'drars', 'feman', 'got', 'urbo']
```

I am just trying to have the code INSERT these strings as 1 row each into the table.

The error specified when running is:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I tried changing the INSERT to:

```
dbShell.executemany("INSERT INTO slackusers (username) VALUES (%s)", (activeUsers,) )
```

But that seems like it's merely treating the entire list as a single string as it yields:

```
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(30)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in the code you pasted:

```
x = 0
for item in ulist:
    idValue = list['members'][x]['name']
    activeUsers.append(str(idValue))
    x += 1
```

Is not the right way to accomplish what you are trying to do.
first list is a reserved word in python and you shouldn't use it as a variable name. I am assuming you meant ulist.

if you really need access to the index of an item in python you can use enumerate:

```
for x, item in enumerate(ulist):
```

but, the best way to do what you are trying to do is something like

```
for item in ulist: # or list['members'] Your example is kinda broken here
    activeUsers.append(str(item['name']))
```

Your first try was:

```
['b2ong', 'dune', 'drble', 'drars', 'feman', 'got', 'urbo']
```

Your second attempt was:

```
(['b2ong', 'dune', 'drble', 'drars', 'feman', 'got', 'urbo'], )
```

What I think you want is:

```
[['b2ong'], ['dune'], ['drble'], ['drars'], ['feman'], ['got'], ['urbo']]
```

You could get this many ways:

```
dbShell.executemany("INSERT INTO slackusers (username) VALUES (%s)", [ [a] for a in activeUsers] )
```

or event better:

```
for item in ulist: # or list['members'] Your example is kinda broken here
    activeUsers.append([str(item['name'])])
dbShell.executemany("""INSERT INTO slickusers (username) VALUES (%s)""", activeUsers)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and information I didn't know about those best practices. In addition, I used your code as well as included a commit() call to the connection object since I just discovered that psycopg2 automatically opens transactions and does not commit unless you specifically do so.